# ASP.NET MVC Query not showing Distinct values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, google-visualization

I am using the following query for use in google charts. It works well but it doesnt show distinct months. Is there a way to sum all the `HoursTaken` per `MonthOfHoliday` to avoid not having distinct values?

```
 var querythpmpro = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                     where r.EmployeeID == id
                     select new { Count = r.HoursTaken, Value = r.MonthOfHoliday.ToString() }).OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```

Error message from the console `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type string in column index 0`

EDIT:

```
#region Total Hours Per Month

        var querythpmpro = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                            where r.EmployeeID == id
                            group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                            select new { Value = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken) }
               ).OrderBy(e => e.Value);


        var resultthpmpro = querythpmpro.ToList();

        var datachartthpmpro = new object[resultthpmpro.Count];
        int Q = 0;
        foreach (var i in resultthpmpro)
        {
            datachartthpmpro[Q] = new object[] { i.Value, i.Sum};
            Q++;
        }
        string datathpmpro = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datachartthpmpro, Formatting.None);
        ViewBag.datajthpmpro = new HtmlString(datathpmpro);

        #endregion
```

Model:

```
   public partial class HolidayRequestForm
  {
     public int RequestID { get; set; }
     public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
     public decimal HoursTaken { get; set; }
     public string Comments { get; set; }
     public int YearCreated { get; set; }
     public int MonthCreated { get; set; }
     public int DayCreated { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> YearOfHoliday { get; set; }
     public Nullable<bool> Approved { get; set; }
     public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
     public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> WorkWeek { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> MonthOfHoliday { get; set; }

     public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
  }
```

Script:

```
  function drawChartA() {

    // Create the data table.

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Value');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
    data.addRows(datassthpmpro);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        'title': 'Holiday Hours Taken Per Month',
        'width': 600,
        'height': 350,
        'hAxis': { title: 'Month Number' },
        'vAxis': { title: 'Holiday Hours Taken' },
        'is3D': true,
        'legend': 'none'
    };
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework. It doesn't execute queries. You're probably asking about Entity Framework or EF Core. Which one is it?

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: @Conor8630 Please add your `HolidayRequestForms` model class to the question please.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about grouping by `MonthOfHoliday` and doing the `Sum` on `HoursTaken`:

```
var querythpmpro = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                     where r.EmployeeID == id
                     group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                     select new { Value =  g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken) }
                   ).OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```

Comment: @Conor8630, why it doesn't seem to work? Is there any error? can you give more info?

Comment: Sorry the chart no longer appears, perhaps its the way the data is being arranged

Comment: Can you look in the console and compare how the data is being retrieved with this group by and how you need it?

Comment: @Conor8630 Isn't it about renaming `Count` property to `Sum`?

Comment: I've added the rest of the code, I did try naming it both names with your query and no luck. Above is what I have now with the rest of the code

Comment: @alaa_sayegh I get the following error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type string in column index 0"

Comment: Try converting the value from `Nullable<int>` to `string` before binding it to the chart.